# work in progress animation when background work is not complete in android

Tags: java, android

In my app, I want to show user some animation when background work is in progress(e.g. like FIle downloading/getting surrent location etc).
How I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use a asyncTask like below.

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
ProgressDialog pd;
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
  super.onPreExecute();
   pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
   pd.setMessage("loading");
   pd.show();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
  // Do your request , eg: file download etc
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
  super.onPostExecute(result);
  if (pd != null)
  {
     pd.dismiss();
  }
}
}
```

call this class like below when you need it like below,

```
new MyTask().execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use progress bar for this purpose. You can create a progress bar and place in a custom dialog box. Or you can use a library for that purpose. I can suggest you some library. Here is some progress bar by Awesome Android UI - 
https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui#progress